# TelephoneSurvey, when to call?

Tags: survey

I conduce a prestudy to understand when is the best time to call bakers for a telephone survey.

Here is my preliminatory study design:

1. I have a table of all 15000 baker firms in a country
2. I select randomly 20 for each hour of day, all but from 19:00 to 23:00 (7pm- 11pm) where I do not expect them to work. 20h * 20 = 400 calls
3. I call them asking them politely if they would answer my survey.
4. For each call I record start and end time The longer the call the better.
5. Also, I record if the baker accepted the survey, and if he answered the phone at all

How would you optimize this design so that I require fewer calls? I think about using bayesian theorem to establish gutt feeling priors. Like, at 03:00 they have to work so the probability is low or at 13:00 the major work is over so they will respond more frequently.

Then I intend to update the bayesian priors with measuremed response rates

Any ideas how to improve my study design? Particularly that I require fewer samples to come to a good judgment when to call?

Comment: I think you'd be better off looking into the literature on telephone survey methods, market research, and how to increase response rates--topics that go far beyond statistics.  Also, your comment about a Bayesian approach is in "the spirit" of Bayesian thinking but does not strictly fit, since you would be using your knowledge as is, to guide implementation, rather than to be combined with observed data to yield a posterior distribution telling "what some quantity is likely to be".

Comment: Would be fun to have a frequency list of most often used swear words dependent on the time of call.

Comment: @rolando2 I will look up literature, but my hypotesis is that timing is crucial, we should be confident about data analysis. Bayesian updating as you describe it is exactly what I intend to do

Comment: @DeerHunter, I will collect this information and hand it over to you. But a first sample of 10 bakers conduced from 10.30 - 11.30 AM showed 9 rejections but no swearing.

Comment: What is the overall loss function? How can you tie the number of calls made during the pre-study with the non-response rate during the main survey? I smell some Monte-Carlo simulation is in order... And BTW, this is an interesting question.

Comment: @DeerHunter. you suggest to simulate the rejection rate? Tieing the numbers of calls with the nonresponse rate during main study is not my interest, I want to maximize the response rate of the main study by calling only when the loss is shown to be minimal

Comment: Yes, to be more precise, diurnal rejection rate curves have to be simulated. Would suggest looking up samples of diurnal attention/concentration curves from psychology and psychophysiology studies. If you want to only maximize the response rate in the main survey, the simplest solution would be to conduct a pre-survey with as many calls per hour as possible, Bayes be d-ed (say, 24 hourly slots with 20 calls per hour). If this is not what you want, you have to state loss function and constraints on the accuracy of the main survey explicitly.